# Reliably automatically detect OOM killer post-mortem

Tags: kernel, memory, out-of-memory

I have a misbehaving service which is being repeatedly OOM killed which I would like to better diagnose. It's being called by a wrapper script, so the best first step I can think of is to have the script check for a trace from the OOM killer when the process exits and report some details for logging/postmortem.

My basic question: what's the most reliable way to check whether an OOM event recently occured? (N.B. because of the behaviour of the service forking processes, it won't necessarily be in a child process).

Obviously I could just parse syslog, but that feels hacky, so I thought I'd ask if there was a better way.